# Simple recursion program in OCaml, iterating until 10

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm trying to create a simple OCaml program using a recursive function which checks an input (x) and either increments by 1 or decrements by 1 until the value of x is 10.

This is what I currently have -

```
let rec until_ten x =
  match x with
  10 -> 1
  | x > 10 -> until_ten x - 1
  | x < 10 -> until_ten x + 1
  ;;
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are using pattern-matching as if it were a succession of `if`. Pattern matching is about the shape of `x`. You can however write `| x when x > 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TheoWinterhalter has given you a good answer, but I will expand slightly.

The OCaml `match` expression takes an expression and a series of patterns. Patterns, in turn, represent possible values of the expression with placeholders for parts of the substructure.

In your `match` expression you are supplying boolean tests rather than patterns. That's not how `match` works. There's no pattern that matches numbers greater than a certain value. Patterns are about structure and specific values (essentially).

You could replace your `match` with `if ... then ... else if ...` to get a meaningful function.

You can, as @TheoWinterhalter suggests, use `match x with ... | x when x > 10 ...`, but this is just an elaborate way of writing an `if` statement.

Comment: Also additionally, what would be the base case for this function? would it be x == 10 -> []? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The base case for this function is the case when x = 10. One way to see this is to note that this is the one case where the function doesn't call itself recursively.

Comment: Note also: `until_ten x - 1` is parsed as `(until_ten x) - 1`  Even if the other issues with control flow are overcome, this will yield infinite recursion, and it's not tail-recursive, so a stack overflow will occur. Use `until_ten (x - 1)` instead.